# Ramsey's Theory and Tic-Tac-Toe analogy.

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I read, briefly, about a connection between Ramsey's Theory and Tic-Tac-Toe.

From my understanding, it went like this:

**Imagine playing Tic-Tac-Toe in a k-dimensional hyper-cube.  There is such a dimension k where, regardless of cheating and foul-play, the game must end with a winner.**

I want to know if this is correct, where $k$ is the solution to Ramsey's Theory.  Are there any other interesting analogies that, say the average high-schooler, would understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that's right - you're basically describing the Hales-Jewett theorem. I would make a few points, though:

- There's more to the theorem than that! You can increase the number of players, as well as the size of the $k$-hypercube (e.g. number of cells in a row).
- This isn't the only problem in Ramsey theory. So saying e.g. "$k$ is the solution to Ramsey's theory" is very misleading: it suggests there is somehow a single problem, or even a "main problem," when in fact there is an incredibly rich supply of wildly different problems. For instance,

  - Ramsey's original theorem: given any $n$ and $r$, there is some $k$ such that if I color the edges of the complete graph on $k$ vertices ($K_k$) with $r$ colors, I can always find a monochromatic $K_n$.
  - The "Happy Ending Problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem. For a given $n$, what is the least $k$ such that any $k$ points in the plane, no three collinear, contain a convex $n$-gon?
  - Van-der-Waerden's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem on arithmetic progressions: For any $r$ and $k$, there is some $N$ such that if I color the first $N$ integers $1$, . . . , $N$ with $r$ colors, there is a monochromatic arithmetic sequence of length $\ge k$.
  - And, of course, the problem that gave rise to this beauty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number.

Comment: Thank you, you've really cleared up a lot of confusion for me.